# Change event isn't fired when triggering click on file input in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm having issues with uploading a file in Edge. The way I am currently doing it works in both Chrome and Firefox but not in edge.

```
<div id="banner-message">
    <button id="UploadButton">Upload</button>
    <input type="file" id="testUploader" style="display: none;" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#UploadButton").on("click", function () {
        $("#testUploader").trigger("click");

        $("#testUploader").on("change", function() {
            console.log("change");
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the upload button I am able to select a file to upload but when I choose a file nothing happens. Whereas when I choose a file in Chrome or Firefox the change event is fired and logged in the console.

Here is a working JSFiddle that shows the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/34688/

Comment: Have you tried without the `display: none;` ? I know that with some navigators (eg: Safari) it's impossible to trigger a click of an hidden element.

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7194628/.

Comment: @Ezhno I tried getting rid of the `display: none` but that didn't seem to have an affect on it. I moved the `change` event to outside of the `click` event though and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: @Quiver I believe it's a bad syntax to put events inside events. That's probably why Edge didn't like it. Does the navigator returned some errors when it was not working ?

Comment: @Ezhno Nope. There were no errors displayed at all :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. I moved the `change` event to outside of the `click` event and all seems to be working now. Not sure why this is only an issue in Edge though.

Working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#UploadButton").on("click", function () {
        $("#testUploader").trigger("click");
    });

    $("#testUploader").on("change", function() {
        console.log("change");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That is anyway the correct solution. Because otherwise you install the `change-listener` on every click on button. And they stack up.

Comment: @AjAX. Good to know. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

> changed "change" to "click"  and it is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#UploadButton").on("click", function () {
        $("#testUploader").trigger("click");

        $("#testUploader").on("click", function() {
            alert("change");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Mind linking to a working example? I tried changing it to click on JSFiddle but it didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because event listener is added after triggering click event. If you really need to add event listener in another listener you need to do it firstly and then trigger this event. So try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#UploadButton").on("click", function () {
        $("#testUploader").on("change", function() {
            console.log("change");
        });

        $("#testUploader").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```